# What does “matrona Julii auguria video et spem non habet” mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

> matrona Julii auguria video et spem non habet

I thought it might mean “I see the augures thanks to Julius‘ wife and he/she has no hope” or “Oh wife of Julius! I see the augures and he has no hope” or even something else, but I don't know which one is the most likely.

**Edit.** This sentence was given to me as an exercise, as far as I know it's not an excerpt from a longer text.

Comment: In the original exercise, is it _videt_ instead of _video_? The sentence seems to make a lot more sense to me that way.

Comment: No the sentence is correct as it is

Answer (score 4):

It's strange without context but not impossible to say:

> I, the wife of Julius, see the omens and he [presumably Julius] has no hope.

Makes sense for a translation exercise, I suppose.

It is also possible that *matrona Iulii* is vocative, and so it would indeed be translated as you have it ("[Oh] wife of Julius!, I see..."). But without punctuation or context, it's impossible to say which is meant.

Answer (score 2):

If you move the word order around, it makes more sense:

> Auguria video et matrona Julii spem non habet

Let's break down each word:

- **Auguria** - "omens, signs", acc., plural and object of the first verb, *video*.
- **Video** - "see", 1st person, singular.

Your first clause then is "I see the omens".

- **Matrona** - "wife", nom., subject of second clause.
- **Julii** - gen., husband of the wife previously mentioned.
- **spem** - "hope", acc., plural, object of the second verb, *habet*.
- **non** - "not".
- **habet** - "have", 3rd person, singular.

The second clause is then, "The wife of Julius does not have hope". This and the previous clause are then joined with the conjunction, *et* (and), so you get:

> I see the omens and the wife of Julius does not have hope.

If by chance your instructor made a mistake and *video* was supposed to be *videt*, then it would be:

> The wife of Julius sees the omens and does not have hope.

Comment: That is probably the intended meaning, but if that is the case, then the original word order is absurd. You could say: *quod ad matronam attinet, auguria video, et spem non habet*, fine. But as it is, I could be wrong and I can't quote chapter and verse to prove it, but it seems downright wrong to me; certainly in prose.

Comment: This sounds probable, I will give an update as soon as I get an answer